# Getting Error while creating a package in java

Tags: java

while creating a package for my file it giving error message

```
error: no source files
```

i'm running this command

```
javac -d .calculator.java
```

Comment: You may be misunderstanding how the -d option works. "If you specify -d C:\myclasses and the class is called com.mypackage.MyClass, then the class file is C:\myclasses\com\mypackage\MyClass.class." and "Note: The directory specified by the -d option is not automatically added to your user class path." See here for more information: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html

Comment: Also, this is the usage format of the javac command: `javac [ options ] [ sourcefiles ] [ classes] [ @argfiles ]` note how you still need to specify the actual source files after the options.

Comment: the `-d` option is short for `(d) directory` meaning destination. your command is missing a space separator between the dot `.` and the `.java` file name: i.e. `javac -d . .calculator.java` , the dot means it will place the compiled result into the current directory, otherwise replace the argument after `-d` with the desitnation directory name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't fully understand what you tried to do there, but you should try

```
javac -d . calculator.java
```

notice the "." is separated from the "calculator" by a space